# Did I wire this thermostat properly?

Tags: hvac

Just want to make sure I have this correct:
Have M1MB 070a BW heat/ac unit w/ a 710152B control board and a Coleman outside condensing unit.
-Have a four wire thermostat. R,Y,G,W
-Have 2 wires coming in from an outside condensing unit. R,W
-Have four wires to connect to from control board R,G,W,Grey (marked "C" on control board)

I've connected R to R, G to G, W to W, Y to the white terminal going to condenser unit, and red terminal connected to outside condenser unit to Grey (marked "C" on control board)

do have pics of rat nest if needed

Comment: Is there a test procedure that you can follow to make sure all functions work properly?

Answer (score 1):

If there's a `Y` terminal on the furnace, you should connect the `Y` wire from the furnace and one of the wires from the condensing unit to it.

I typically connect the red wire from the condensing unit to `Y`, and the white to `C`. Not that it really matters, that's just how I do it.

Other than that, it sounds good.